# How to populate an email To/CC field based on checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am using Excel VBA to auto-generate a set of emails to be sent daily based on a datasheet we populate every morning.

The individuals receiving the email change depending on the contents.
The individuals can be grouped (e.g. IT, Finance, HR, ...), with some minor overlap.

My thought was to create a checkbox for each group, so that whoever is generating the emails that day can check off the groups and have it populate the To or CC field.

I originally thought to use formulas based on the linked True/False checkbox cell, but that quickly gets messy and doesn't allow me to add multiple groups at the same time.

My next idea was to create a table with a row for each individual and a column identifying their respective group, but I'm not sure where to go from there to populate the To/CC fields.

I included the macro to generate the email below. I'm hoping for some pointers in the right direction.

```vb
Sub SendEmail_Test()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim NewEmaiItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Set NewEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

NewEmailItem.To = "abc@def.com"
NewEmailItem.CC = "abc@def.com"
NewEmailItem.Subject = Format(Date, "mmmm dd") & " info: Subject"
NewEmailItem.Display True

End Sub
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please share a screenshot to show your data layout and checkbox.

Comment: I've added a link to a screenshot in the original post. The table underneath the checkboxes is what changes daily (it gets generated from an unrelated data sheet). I didn't post the table with emails, though I can create a mockup if helpful! It's really just two columns - the first has the corresponding group (IT, HR...) and the second the individual's email.

Answer (score 0):

As the email address appears to be in the column one to the right of the checkbox (rather than in the label of the checkbox) you'll need to find the `TopLeftCell` property of each checkbox.

**Note 1:** This assumes you're using the Form Control Checkbox and not the ActiveX Checkbox.

**Note 2:**  In this image the `TopLeftCell` is in B2 as the control handles are in B2, while the actual checkbox would appear to be in B3.
[image]

I've added a third column of checkboxes to show how you could look in more than one column for your CC addresses.
I've also included some [With statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)  as it shortens the code a bit.

```
Sub SendEmail_Test()

    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
    
    Dim NewEmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set NewEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Dim ToField As String
    Dim CCField As String
    
    Dim chkBox As CheckBox  
    'Look at each checkbox on the sheet in turn.
    For Each chkBox In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes
        With chkBox.TopLeftCell
            If chkBox.Value = 1 Then
                Select Case .Column 'Look at the TopLeftCell.Column property.
                    Case 2 'Column B contains TO address checkboxes.
                        ToField = ToField & chkBox.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1) & "; "
                    Case 5, 8 'Column E & H contains CC
                        CCField = CCField & chkBox.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1) & "; "
                End Select
            End If
        End With
    Next chkBox
    'Remove the last semicolon for each string.
    If Len(ToField) > 0 Then ToField = Left(ToField, Len(ToField) - 2)
    If Len(CCField) > 0 Then CCField = Left(CCField, Len(CCField) - 2)
    
    With NewEmailItem
        .To = ToField
        .CC = CCField
        .Subject = Format(Date, "mmmm dd") & " info: Subject"
        .Display True
    End With

End Sub
```

In the code you've posted you've used `NewEmailItem`, but declared `NewEmaiItem`.  With `Option Explicit` in place this would cause a *Variable not defined* error at compile time.
*Tools > Options > Require Variable Declaration* will put Option Explicit at the top of all new modules.
[image]

**Edit:**  Having just re-read your question.  When you talk about Groups do you mean *Outlook Contact Groups*?  If not can you add a mock-up of your email group sheet please.